# Sort, rank, groupby and sum combined -> Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe with paragraph pairs. There are around 500 paragraphs and each is listed as a pair in the following format (sorted by paragraphA and ranked by highest prediction):

```
ParagraphA | paragraphB | label | prediction

Paragraph1 | Pragraph2  | 1 ----| 0.9890


Paragraph1 | Pragraph10  | 1 ----| 0.9870


Paragraph1 | Pragraph17  | 0 ----| 0.9860


Paragraph1 | Pragraph34  | 1 ----| 0.9820
```

I already sorted and grouped this (beforehand the paragraphs and predictions were in random order):

```
sorted_grouped = df.sort_index(by=['paragraphA', 'predictions'], ascending=[True, False])
```

This is a ranking problem where I tried to predict the likelihood that there was a link between paragraphs. I would now like to measure precision based on the number of links that actually exist (see 'label').

How would I count the number of '1's under label for each Paragraph (under paragraphA) and also the number of times these '1's appear in the top x results? (x is based on the total number of '1's for that paragraph. If there were seven '1's, I would look at the top seven results)

For my example above, let's say there are overall three '1's under label for Paragraph1, but in the top three, there are only two '1's.

I would therefore like to extract that info:

1) Overall 1's = 3

2) 1's in top 3 = 2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood if column "label" has only numbers, or if the entries are like the one shown (i.e. '1 ----'). In this case I suggest to first create a new column in this way:

```
df['new_label'] = df['label'].astype(str).str[0]
df['new_label'] = df['new_label'].astype(int)
```

Ignore this passage if 'label' column is already filled with only numbers, and use 'label' instead of 'new_label' in the following
(I also assume that values in column 'new_label' are only either 0 or 1):

```
 total = df.groupby('ParagraphA')['new_label'].sum() # this gives you the number of 1s
percentage = df.groupby('ParagraphA')['new_label'].apply(lambda g : g.head(g.sum()).sum() / g.sum()) # this gives you the percentage of 1s in the first x rows
```

Comment: Hi Daniele! Thank you for your answer! The first line to calculate the total works well, but for the percentage - my problem is that each percentage is based on the "total" for that paragraph...therefore the x changes for each paragraph. Can I somehow loop through that and calculate the total number of '1's in the first x rows (with x being the total for that paragraph)? So the end result would be: 1) Paragraph 1 | 3 (total 1s) | 2 (number of 1s in the first 3 rows for that paragraph) and so on

Comment: With my formula, what you obtain is: Paragraph 1 | 3 (total 1s) | 0.66 (percentage of 1s in the first 3 rows, in other words 2/3). If you want to have just "2", do not divide by x.sum()

Comment: As regards the loop over the different groups (i.e. paragraphs): this is exactly what groupby + apply does: it evaluates the function for each group, in our case for each paragraph